# How to set color for Maximum and Minimum Value bar in Clustered Column Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Let's say, I've the following Pivot Table generated from a Random Sales Dataset.

[image]

And the corresponding Pivot Chart.

[image]

How can one make the Maximum & Minimum value bar of "Sum Of Profit" of Green and Red Color respectively? Also, when more data is added in the dataset, color of the bar should **update automatically** when the Min. and Max. value changes.

Comment: I believe this would require VBA

Comment: You can refer to this article: https://www.xelplus.com/highlight-max-min-values-in-an-excel-line-chart/